# I am writting documnt to my marklogic Document database but geeting an error "write single document: cannot process response with 404 status'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, marklogic

i have made new http server on port 9700 and also provide all the roles like rest-writer ,rest-reader 
[image: env.js is my connection file]
[image: load.js is used to write the document to database]

Comment: Screenshots should not be the primary means of communicating information. The people you expect to answer your question need text (and so does google, so that people with your exact issues might discover your question). Paste the code and response into code blocks.

Comment: For a proper answer, you'd need to provide information about your db configuration like HTTP end-points, ports etc. Since you're going with screenshot - why not provide a screenshot of your admin screen and details of the HTTP endpoint you're trying to reach on MarkLogic.

Answer (score 3):

Although you have created an HTTP server, you also need to create an instance of the REST-API on that server. Otherwise, it won't have the MarkLogic REST-API endpoints available.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021

> Before you can use the REST Client API, you must have access to an instance that consists of an HTTP App Server specially configured to handle REST Client API requests, a content database, and a modules database.

## [Creating an Instance](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021)